What seat setting should a 5'11 gentleman use on the optima series chest press?
I.E. the chest press machine in the 30 minute express workout room at planet fitness. It is the optima series chest press. I don't know which height setting to put the seat to. What would a 5'11 gentleman use for the seat height setting? 5?

I suspect this will depend on your body shape as well as height.  I am 6'2" tall, but I have a long back and relatively short legs, so I would not have the same settings as someone 6'2" tall, but with a more normal body shape for that height (i.e. relatively long legs and arms).  I am not an expert, but I think you need to adjust the machine to get your arms in the right place with respect to your chest - if you know what that should be, you can adjust the machine to suit you.

@DikranMarsupial if i require the lowest seat setting on the optima series shoulder press, which is 8,  should i also use the lowest seat setting on the chest press, which is 7?

In general, what you want is for the axles/pivot points to line up with joints, and for joints to be against edges of seats.
As an example, for a leg lift machine, you would want the pivot point of the leg lever to be in line with your knee, the back of your knee at the edge of the seat, the seat back moved forward so you sit upright, and the pad of the bar at the curve of your ankle/foot.
That being said, everyone has different limb lengths and proportions, so your best course of action is to have the attendants at the studio show you how to properly adjust for yourself.
